# I don't get Linux kernel 5.x.x upgrades. I just get kernel 4.x.x upgrades

Tags: kernel

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (with the additional support life through extra PPA backports).

Some weeks ago I upgraded the Linux kernel from 4.x.x to 5.x.x

But... I still receive upgrades of the 4.x.x kernel, and I don't receive any upgrade to the last 5.x.x.

Is it normal?

Is it something wrong, here?

Do I have to manually uninstall the 4.x.x kernel?

Comment: With an standard `Terminal` session and `sudo apt-get install` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

Is in official source.

```
 apt-cache policy linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 5.0.0.17.73
  Versionstabelle:
     5.0.0.17.73 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        5.0.0.16.72 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this data!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you manually install the latest mainline/stable kernel you also have to manually install the updates which generally occur about once a week.

See: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)